# Go from wide-table format to long-table (dynamic)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to go from a 'wide-formatted' table [see image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne0DM.png) to a 'long-formatted' table [see image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBZYy.png) using Google Spreadsheets.

I have created an spreadsheet to re-create the scenario, having this in mind:

- Data is being updated by users on tab 'wide'
- Id's can be added at any time (no Ids can be removed)
- Tags can be replaced, removed or even a new tag can be added (limit is 9 tags)

Test document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lKAFCON2Bh8n3etGKTEFI3LklGdfMT0wrKm1JyoOHag/edit?usp=sharing

Tab 'wide' has an example of how data is originally formatted.
Tab 'long' is the expected output (all id-tags possible unique combinations)

**Which is the best approach to get a 'long-table' formatted data that also enables me to capture any update on the original source of data?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={"id"\ "tag"; ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(
 IF(wide!B2:Z="";;wide!A2:A&"♦"&wide!B2:Z)); 
 "where Col1 is not null"); "♦"))}
```

[image]

Comment: the first part of the formula was throwing me an error `{"id"\ "tag";...` I just removed it and force the column header names to be Id and tag and it worked! Thank you very much @player0!